# Classic pages which use LoadSodByKey('require.js') now fails with a modern SPFX webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

Classic pages with modern spfx now fails if you load require.js with LoadSodByKey since last week. Any idea how to fix or how to report this to Microsoft?

```
LoadSodByKey("require.js", function () {
  // stuff
}
```

With modern SPFX webpart (Version: 1.4.1 -> "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "~1.4.1") requirejs fails to load and is undefined. HTTP request with  require.js did work but require is still undefined... Loadingproblems but it works like 1/20 times.

Thanks for any kind of help.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

I build a workaround with cleanRequireJS();.

First you have to check if all your modern SPFX webparts are loaded (i check there divs), wait for that situation with setTimeout/loop and AFTER that i make cleanRequireJS(); and load SP "require.js" and all other stuff we use this for.

Best regards!